# How to save login and password in Firefox, when website has not remeber credentials feature?

Tags: firefox, passwords, cache, auto-login, autosave

I use the website on daily basis and it does not have "save login and password" feature. I don't use Firefox's password manager. Is it possible to bypass login page, to save the cache, where the credentials are stored of that specific site?

Comment: Check cookies to see if there's one to keep you logged in.

Comment: There are cookies, I also added that website to allow cookies list. The problem is, they get expired after some time. How do I make them permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a Firefox add-on, [Cookie Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/a-cookie-manager/) to edit cookies. It can edit the expiration date.